# Need help Aligning list and image (HTML CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

Im trying to align my image that is defined in a div statement next to a list.

```css
  body {
  background-color: #3799DF;
  color: #1B78BB;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: #3799DF;
  background-image: url(FullLogoBanner.png);
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 105%;
  max-height: 250px;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header a:link {
  color: #40407A
}

header a:visited {
  color: #40407A
}

header a:hover {
  color: #FFF
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 6em;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: #1B78BB;
  padding: 0.7em;
  background-color: #8ADFFF;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #000000;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #40407A;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #3799DF;
  border: 2px groove #333333;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: #8ADFFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 8em;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

main {
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  display: block;
}

section {
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
}

footer {
  font-size: .70em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #8ADFFF;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home {
  height: 40vh;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.content {
  height: 40vh;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

#mobile {
  display: inline;
}

#desktop {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 2em;
}

#homeimg {
  background-image: url(petstore_dog.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: contain;
  display: none;
}

.header {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#center {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin: auto;
}

#left {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #3799DF;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #3799DF;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #89CFF0;
}

caption {
  margin: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 1em;
  width: 80%;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

@media (min-width: 645px) {
  header {
    background-color: #3799DF;
    background: url(LogoDesign2.png) no-repeat left, url(Pawprints.png) repeat-x bottom, url(Pawprints.png) repeat-x;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    font-size: 150%;
    max-height: 355px;
  }
  .home {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  .content {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  section {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
  }
  #homeimg {
    display: block;
  }
  #flow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  form {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-template-columns: 12em 1fr;
    width: 60%;
  }
  input[type="submit"] {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    width: 9em;
  }
  label {
    float: right;
  }
  #mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: inline;
  }
  table {
    width: 80%;
  }
  @media (min-width: 1045px) {
    header {
      background: url(LogoDesign1.png) no-repeat left, url(LogoDesign1.png) no-repeat right, url(Pawprints.png) repeat-x, url(Pawprints.png) repeat-x bottom;
      font-size: 160%;
    }
    .home {
      height: 50vh;
    }
    .content {
      height: 50vh;
    }
    #wrapper {
      margin: auto;
      width: 75%;
    }
    footer {
      margin: auto;
      width: 75%;
    }
    table {
      width: 65%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <main>

    <h2>Your Local Pet Shop</h2>
    <p><span class="name">Furry Baby</span> is the best place to go for all your pet shopping needs in the Hyde Park area. We provide options for all your favorite furry friends including: Dogs, Cats, and Birds.
      <br>Our services have allowed pet owners to thrive with their best friends since 1989. Come to <span class="name">Furry Baby</span> and let your animal companion live their best life!</p>

    <p>We cater towards cat, dog, and bird owners!<br> Currently we sell:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Leashes</li>
      <li>Collars</li>
      <li>Toys</li>
      <li>Treats</li>
      <li>Cages</li>
      <li>And more!</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="homeimg">
    </div>

    <span class="name">Furry Baby</span><br> 123 Hyde Park North<br> Tampa, Florida, 33606<br><br>
    <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a>
    <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>


  </main>
```

I've tried using a flexbox row container to align them and it does not work, I've tried setting them both to float left and right, respectively. Ideally, I would want the picture on the left and the list on the right but no matter what I try either the list ends up off the page/unaligned or the image just doesn't show up if I put it to float.

Answer (score 1):

so I would start with making sure that I understand css flexbox properly. By this I mean reading those articles:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And later on I would try to implement flexbox in similar fashion to the snippet below. You are on the right track, just keep on going :)

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between w-full bg-yellow">
  <ul class="bg-red">
    <li>Leashes</li>
    <li>Collars</li>
    <li>Toys</li>
    <li>Treats</li>
    <li>Cages</li>
    <li>And more!</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="homeimg" class="bg-blue">
    There will be some img I guess.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your content in a `.wrapper` class, and apply flexbox to it, and group your two sections into divs. Something like this:

```css
body { background-color: #3799DF;
    color:#1B78BB;
        font-family: Arial;
        margin: 0; color: white; }

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<main>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="homeimg">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/36717/amazing-animal-beautiful-beautifull.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <h2>Your Local Pet Shop</h2>
    <p><span class="name">Furry Baby</span> is the best place to go for all your pet shopping needs
in the Hyde Park area. We provide options for all your favorite furry friends including: Dogs, Cats, and Birds.
<br>Our services have allowed pet owners to thrive with their best friends since 1989. Come to <span class="name">Furry Baby</span>
and let your animal companion live their best life!</p>

    <p>We cater towards cat, dog, and bird owners!<br> Currently we sell:</p>
    <ul>
       <li>Leashes</li>
       <li>Collars</li>
       <li>Toys</li>
       <li>Treats</li>
       <li>Cages</li>
       <li>And more!</li>
    </ul>
    
    <span class="name">Furry Baby</span><br>
    123 Hyde Park North<br>
    Tampa, Florida, 33606<br><br>
    <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a>
    <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>
  </div>

    
  </div>
</main>
```